# Querying efficiently from an index table

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb, indexing

I have a MySQL table in which 1000s of posts are indexed as follows

[image]

First column contains the keyword, second, the number of occurrences and in the 3rd column there is an array in which each index contains an array of length 3 such that 1st index represents the id of the post, 2nd the number of occurrences in that post and 3rd index contains an array of line numbers in which the keyword is found.

Now I want to create a search engine where users can search for posts based on keywords. The most basic solution would be to fetch all the results for each keyword from a mysql query and then find all the common post ids using javascript (as I am using Node).

I know there must be ways for making this efficient. I think of using MongoDB, but I am unsure whether it will work.
And also I cannot use elastic search.

Comment: Why isn't this normalized?

Comment: I had the same reaction when I saw the db. But the indexing has been done by someone else and this is what finally I have.

Comment: "I think of using MongoDB" - if changing the database (to something radically different) is an approach you're considering, then surely transforming this into a more queryable form in the same database is not off the table?

Comment: True, but indexing is not I can do but, if required, I was thinking of transforming it into MongoDB using python script and not by performing indexing again.

Comment: yes, yes, use python script and transform this into normalized form. It's not any different.

Comment: Ok I understood your point. So after normalization the table should have in total 4 columns  one for keyword 2nd for postId 3rd for occurance and 4th for the line numbers. Correct ?

Comment: This is still somewhat denormalized, but should be much more queryable, yes.

Comment: Yes, the 4th column is still denormalized. But it will work. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a purpose for the count other than helping to parse the comma separated list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For normalization, you'd probably want at least two tables.

One for just holding the keywords (and an easily and quickly referenced keyword_id value).

A second table for the "index", holding (keyword_id, post_id, line_number). The existence of fields holding counts becomes a bit redundant when simple "count" queries on this index table can yield the same results without needing to be kept synchronized with string data.

Then to find posts with your keywords, you can just do a query like this:

```
SELECT i.post_id, COUNT(DISTINCT i.keyword_id) AS keywordsUsed 
FROM keywords AS k
INNER JOIN keywords_index AS i ON k.keyword_id = i.keyword_id
WHERE k.keyword IN ( 'your', 'list', 'of', 'keywords')
GROUP BY i.post_id
ORDER BY keywordsUsed DESC
;
```

or this

```
SELECT post_id, COUNT(DISTINCT keyword_id) AS keywordsUsed 
FROM keywords_index 
WHERE keyword_id IN (
   SELECT keyword_id 
   FROM keywords 
   WHERE keyword IN ( 'your', 'list', 'of', 'keywords')
)
GROUP BY post_id
ORDER BY keywordsUsed DESC
;
```

Another thing worth keeping in mind is that while this table feels much bigger (lots more rows), it will probably take up much less actual space (and be faster to access because of it):

The string `[[113, 1, [822]], [199, 1, [11592]],[267, 1, [5293` is a minimum of 50 bytes (assuming single byte character set), not counting length specifier for the string itself. Even removing the count values and associated commas and spaces only reduces the data by 9 bytes.

`113, 822
199, 11592
267, 5293`
is 24 bytes, assuming INT is used for the id values.

Comment: "The existence of fields holding counts becomes a bit redundant" - yeeeeah, that's until you need to sort by counts/popularity :) And sort quickly, that is.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev With appropriate indexing, calculating counts should be relatively quick anyway; packing the subcounts into that string field still would have been worse, and it's questionable if the unpacked count the original design had would have been useful since it might count five references in one post with the same weight as single distinct references in five posts. My suggested design allows for counting total overall references, distinct posts with references, and references within a post relatively quickly. If better performance was really needed, a summary table could be created.

Answer (score 0):

Select query should be something like this:

`Select {third column name} from {table name} where {first column name} like %?%`

so if you pass in `agree` you should get `[[2,1,[673], [7,3,[303, 2863, 2866],[9,2,[...]]`

This should return your array which you should be able to `map()` over

if you want the first index...

```
{array}.map((subArray) => subArray[0]); //returns an array of the first index
```

this would return `[2,7,9]`

If you are trying to get the third index and combine them you should be able to do a `foreach()` and `concat()`

```
let sample = [];
{array}.forEach((subArray) => { sample = sample.concat(subArray);});
```

This would return `[673, 303, 2863, 2866, ...]

Comment: Thanks. But this is what I am doing right now. I was thinking of a more efficient solution.

Comment: I think the only way to be more efficient is to alter your data structure.

Comment: True. I'll have to normalize it, to make it efficient.